# Error status code is not getting written to serilog file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logging, error-handling, serilog

In .net core (6) i am using serilog for loging. Not ysing any custom templates or not writing separe logs with api requests. Log is working properly even errors. The problem is that i need error status code also.. but the log does not have error status code. I tried changing levels and no effects what so ever. Can any one check my settings and suggest what i am doing wrong.

AppSettings

```
"Serilog":{
    "MinimumLevel": {
    "Default": "Information"
    "Override":{
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    "Microsoft": "Warning"
    "System": "Warning"
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Http.DefaultHttpclientFactory": "Warning
    "GPS.Common.HostSetup": "Warning"
    "System.Net .Http.Httpclient": "Warning"
    "CorrelationId": "Information",
    "HealthChecks.UI": "Warning
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "Warning"
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks": "Warning"
    "System.Net .Http.Httpclient.health-checks": "Warning"
    }
    },
```

And c# code

```
public static WebApplicationBuilder Configure(this WebApplicationBuilder webAppBuilder)
{
webAppBuilder. SetupKestrelConfiguration();
webAppBuilder.Host.UseSerilog((ctx, lc) => lc
   ReadFrom.Configuration(webAppBuilder.Configuration)
   ConfigureDestructure()
   Enrich.FromLogcontext()
   Enrich.WithAssemblyName()
   Enrich.WithAssemblyVersion()
   Enrich.WithMachineName()
   Enrich.WithCorrelationIdHeader()
   Enrich.WithProperty("xxx", "API"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check this [document](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore#serilogaspnetcore---),add the package `Serilog.AspNetCore`

add the middleware `app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();` to your middleware pipeline

I tried a minimal example with your appsettings

```
builder.Host.UseSerilog((context,config)=>config.ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration));
.....
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();
app.UseRouting();
```

Result:

[image]